# QT creator (can't find '__main__' module in '') error

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-creator, pyqt6

I have made a brand new project in "Qt Creator" but every time I run it (without even editing anything) i get this error:
20:28:30: Starting C:\Users\aonob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -u ""...
C:\Users\aonob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't find '**main**' module in ''
20:28:31: C:\Users\aonob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe exited with code 1

How can I fix this?

im using python 3.10.6

here is the main.py file code:
`

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    qml_file = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "main.qml"
    engine.load(qml_file)
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

`

Comment: It seems like Qt Creator is trying to run the whole project instead of the file (the hint is the empty quotes as arguments of `python.exe`). I don't use Creator, but you should be able to set which script to specifically run. Otherwise, add the `__init__.py` in the root of the project dir and change the contents accordingly. Note: if you run the code as usual (from the command line `python.exe main.py`) it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, but solved it by following the steps below.

1. temporarily remove all paths except main.py from .pyproject
2. run the project and it should work fine
3. restore the paths in .pyproject
4. should run without problems

Perhaps this bug is due to QtCreator's auto-detection thing for the main script not working properly, but I can get it to recognize the main script by following the above steps.